# Torah reading at fast day mincha services if the fast will not be completed?

Tags: torah-reading, fast-days, mincha-afternoon-prayer

Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 566:3 rules that the *chazzan* does not recite *aneinu* at *mincha* of a fast day unless there are ten people present who are fasting. Mishnah Berurah 14 rules that the same applies to *keriat hatorah* of *mincha*. (It's possible that different rules apply to the four fasts connected to the Destruction of the Temple. Leave that to one side.)

Mishnah Berurah 15 also rules that if one of those ten people will not complete the fast (even though you have ten who are fasting right now) the *chazzan* does not recite *aneinu*.

What about the Torah reading? Does the same rule apply? If you have ten fasting at *mincha*, but you know that they will not all complete the fast, do you read from the Torah?